# Telnet return unrecognized command

Tags: windows-server-2008, telnet

Maybe someone could explain how to use Telnet to test Virtual SMTP Server on another machine with Windows 2008?

I have tried command below and get `unrecognized command` error. (The actual server deomain replaced with xxxxx)

```
Telnet smtp.xxxxx.com 25
220 xxxxx.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 7.0.6002.18222 rea
dy at  Tue, 23 Oct 2012 15:57:18 +0300
FROM: tomas@MyDomain.com
500 5.3.3 Unrecognized command
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntex needs to start with helo dominaname.com. Example below. Make sure to use enter spaces correct and the period at the end.

```
    telnet xxx.domainname.com 25
    helo domainname.com
    mail from: myaddress@domain.com 
    rcpt to:youraddress@domain.com 
    data 

    to: myaddress@domain.com
    from: myaddress@domain.com    
    Subject:This is a test

    Testing

    .
```

If your lazy just use http://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx

Assuming its a external server.

Comment: If `mail from: myaddress@domain.com` causes 502 Unrecognized command, try `mail from: <myaddress@domain.com>`.